# Function won't store cookie

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I am trying to create then retrieve a cookie in javascript. I am using Google Chrome and when I run the code below it doesnt store the cookie after page reload.

Below is my code

```
   <html>
       <title> Cookies </title>
         <body onload="checkCookie()">
         <script type="text/javascript">

        function getCookie(c_name){
            var c_value = document.cookie;
            var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
            if (c_start == -1){
                c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
            }
            if (c_start == -1){
                c_value = null;
            }else{
                c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
                var c_end = c.value.indexOf(";", c_start);

            if (c_end ==-1){
                c_end = c_value.lenth;
            }
            c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
            }
            return c_value;
        }

        function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays){
            var exdate = new Date();
            exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
            var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
            document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
        }

        function checkCookie(){
            var username = getCookie("username");
            if(username!=null && username!=""){
                alert("Welcome again " + username);
            }else{
                username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");
                if(username!=null && username!=""){
                    setCookie("username",username,365);
                    document.write(username);
                }


            }
        }

    </script>
<body>
```

Im not sure why it isnt working, I literaly copy/pasted it from here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: anti-w3schools shitstorm in 3 .. 2  .. 1 ....  But first, do you get any error messages? Have you verified that the code is actually executed?

Comment: The problem is not in setting the cookie

Comment: how are you using it?

Comment: @GolezTrol Yea, if you go to the bottom of the page in the link I just sent you it lets you try it yourself and it works there

Comment: @raam86 I am just learning how to use cookies, can you try using it and telling me if it works for you? All that happens is a box appears and says what is your name, then next time you open then page it says Hello again "name"

Comment: Here's a fiddle. Not sure what it is doing.  http://jsfiddle.net/Awzyq/11/

Comment: @Paul it checks for cookie existence and then stores it with immediate expiry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that was some fun bit of debuggin. Thank you [W3Schools](http://www.w3fools.com/). Next Time I suggest you use your console and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

First bug that is fairly easy to see is:

```
c_end = c_value.lenth; //
```

#### Should be:

```
c_end = c_value.length;//
```

If you use the code you will notice the console alerts `c is not defined.`

Ok We run the function one by one and we see we get the error when running `getCookie`

### Ok inspect!

```
function getCookie(){
//Weird use if getIndex
//Someone forgot about regex
//..
 c_end = c.value.length; // AHA!!!
}
```

#### should be:

```
c_end = c_value.length;
```

As for your other problem

`setCookie` uses `new date()` for the expiry which means immediately

use:

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays){
            var exdate = exdays;
/....
}
```

Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks, How do I show the console, I use sublime text, is it in that or the browser?

Comment: It is in the browser. Hit F12 and welcome yourself to the world of javascript also http://eloquentjavascript.net/

Comment: did you get the code to work? Because it still isnt working for me.

Comment: for me the cookie still isnt being stored

Comment: I updated the code in my question, do you see anything wrong with it ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33053/discussion-between-user222786-and-raam86)

Comment: Figured it out, I was opening the files localy from my computer, I had to use MAMP or WAMP to get it to work. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @user222786 don't worry about it. Have fun